# Can derived class use friend function of the basis class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

If I have some class Basis, and derived from it Derived, inside basis I have friend function

```
friend int operator!=(const Basis&, const Basis&)
```

Inside derived class I don't have such function
So my question is if I have inside my main

```
If( derived1 != derived2 ) ...
```

why does it work? i don't have any constructor for casting for != thanks in advance
If I write
if ( derived != basis ) will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is comparing them as objects of class `Basis`.  Since you can always implicitly convert from a derived class to a base class, the compiler is able to pass them to the `Basis` overload of `operator !=`.  Of course, this comparison can only use fields declared in `Basis`, so if you want the comparison to be more specific by using members of `Derived`, you'll have to define a separate `operator !=` overload.

The friendship declaration isn't relevant when it comes to calling `operator !=`; all it does is allow `operator !=` to access private members declared in `Basis`.

Comment: @Chan, yes, any combination of objects of type `Basis` or a derived class could be compared with your `operator !=` overload, with the caveat that the overload only uses the parts inherited from `Basis`.  This is a consequence of the basic OO 'is-a' inheritance relationship. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your friend function only compares the `Basis` parts of `Derived`. So, it works after a fashion, but ignores any data in `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your Derived class inherits everything that your Basis class has, which in this case is an operator overload for !=, your Derived objects (derived1 and derived2) also have them defined.